# Looping through UL list but can't prepend div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to loop through list items in javascript and prepend some HTML to EACH list item. However, when I create the loop the content only gets prepended to the LAST element.

So in my example, I'm looking for the `circle +` to be before ALL list items, not just the last.

```js
var _el = document.createElement("div");
_el.setAttribute("class","circle plus");

var _hp_li = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

_hp_li.forEach(function(e){
    e.prepend(_el);
});
```

```css
ul{list-style:none;}

.circle{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #fff;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
}

.circle:before,
.circle:after{
    content:'';position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
}

.circle.plus:before,
.circle.plus:after {
    background:#000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff9e;
}
.circle.plus:before{
    width: 2px;
    margin: 3px auto;
}
.circle.plus:after{
    margin: auto 3px;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
<li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the definition for the `_el` variable inside of the `forEach` will do the trick. This will ensure that a new element is created for each iteration of the loop.

```js
var _hp_li = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

_hp_li.forEach(function(e){
    var _el = document.createElement("div");
    _el.setAttribute("class","circle plus");
    e.prepend(_el);
});
```

```css
ul{list-style:none;}

.circle{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #fff;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
}

.circle:before,
.circle:after{
    content:'';position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
}

.circle.plus:before,
.circle.plus:after {
    background:#000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff9e;
}
.circle.plus:before{
    width: 2px;
    margin: 3px auto;
}
.circle.plus:after{
    margin: auto 3px;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
<li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. I kept it out of the loop because I didn't want to recreate it every time. I didn't realize I couldn't reuse it in this manner. Once SO allows me to accept the answer I will.

Comment: @imvain2 Glad to help. Have you looked into using a library like React by any chance? Things like this are a lot easier when using React

Comment: No, but this is a rare issue that is only coming up because of content from a CMS and the design. I tried creating the circle plus without any additional elements but never got it right, but this one does work.

Answer (score 1):

You were prepending the same element multiple times. I believe you can only have an instance of an element at one point in the DOM, so only the last change stuck.

It works if you create a separate instance of the `div` for each list item.

```js
var _hp_li = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

_hp_li.forEach(function(e){
    var _el = document.createElement("div");
    _el.setAttribute("class","circle plus");
    
    e.prepend(_el);
});
```

```css
ul{list-style:none;}

.circle{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #fff;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
}

.circle:before,
.circle:after{
    content:'';position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
}

.circle.plus:before,
.circle.plus:after {
    background:#000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff9e;
}
.circle.plus:before{
    width: 2px;
    margin: 3px auto;
}
.circle.plus:after{
    margin: auto 3px;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
<li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```